# Como reordeno un array al revez en c++

Tags: c++

como podria hacer que este vector se de la vuelta para verificar si la palabra es palindroma o no, el siguiente codigo ingresa un string y lo separa dentro de un vector

```
#include <string> 
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int i;
    string palabra;
    cout << "ingrese una palabra: "<< endl; cin >> palabra;
    i = palabra.length();
    string vec[i]; 
    for(int j = 0; j<= i - 1; j++){
        vec[j] = palabra.substr(j, 1);
        cout << vec[j];
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

tomando en cuenta que aun no lo esta ordenando al revez
el output de esto quedaria asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No necesitas hacer nada de eso. Usa dos apuntadores. Uno al final de la palabra y otro al inicio. Y vas comparando el carácter en el índice de cada apuntador. Eso en un ciclo while. Si las dos letras son distintas, rompes el ciclo o retornas `false`.

Comment: Debo aprender a usar punteros jaja en mi universidad aun no llegamos a eso, lo que me dices tiene mas sentido que lo que yo queria hacer jaja gracias

Comment: Por punteros me refiero a dos integers. Uno con el valor de la última posición de la palabra. El otro con el inicio de la palabra. Es decir uno con valor de 0 y otro con valor de length - 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No necesitas invertir la palabra, o convertirla en un arreglo. Simplemente puedes recorrer la palabra, comparando el primer carácter y el último, y moviéndotelo hacía el centro del string.

La forma más sencilla en la que no requires invertir la palabra, y tan solo usar la que ya tienes es la siguiente:

```
#include <string> 
using namespace std;

int main() {
    bool esPalindromo;
    int izq, der;
    string palabra;

    cout << "ingrese una palabra: " << endl; cin >> palabra;
    
    izq = 0;
    der = palabra.length() - 1;
    esPalindromo = true;

    while (izq <= der) {
        if (palabra[izq] != palabra[der]) {
            isPalindromo = false;
            break;
        }

        izq++;
        der--;
    }

    cout << isPalindromo; 
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Gracias me salvaste la vida

Answer (score 2):

Si ya tienes la palabra en un `string`, como es tu caso, para invertir la palabra puedes usar `std::reverse`

```
std::string inversa = cadena;
std::reverse(inversa.begin(), inversa.end());
```

O también puedes invertir la cadena usando el constructor de `std::string`:

```
std::string inversa(cadena.rbegin(), cadena.rend());
```